# What needs to be corrected in the code to make it work on smartphones?

Tags: javascript

This code launches a video at the click of a button. But it doesn't work on smartphones. Where I made a mistake?

```js
const Player = document.getElementById('player2');
const PlayBtn = document.getElementById('play');
const stopBtn = document.getElementById('stop');
let times = 0, playY;
const playVideo = PlayBtn.addEventListener( 'click' , () => {
    if(times == 0){
      playY = Player.src += '?autoplay=1';
      times = 1;
    }
});

stopBtn.addEventListener( 'click' , () => {
    playY = playY.slice(0, -11);
    Player.src = playY
    times = 0;
});
```

```html
<div class="video-frame">
  <iframe id="player2" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/G9J-KcqcQYY" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<button id="play">Play</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Is the video an `iframe` or a `video` element?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier iframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not using anything like Babel, I assume you just need to change all your `const` and `let` to `var` and also your arrow functions to normal, because some browsers still don't understand newest ECMA syntax.

You could also try to use this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/AmrSubZero/pen/oLOYrA) I've found for you. I tested it myself on my own video and it seems to be working as a charm. But only for YouTube video since it utilizes it's own API so you don't need to play around with cutting parts of you link to get video stopped/played.

A couple things to remember. As you will notice only "older" syntax is used there and you will also need to add `?enablejsapi=1&html5=1` to the end of your link in order to get API enabled

Comment: I'm not convinced, smartphones usually are on par with the latest browser technologies. caniuse states that [const](https://caniuse.com/#feat=const) and [let](https://caniuse.com/#feat=let) support are strong in the mobile browsers. Except for Opera Mini, but I would not consider that being *smartphone* territory.

Comment: You may be correct with this, but I had exactly same issue with trying to run my js code on my phone using Chrome if I remember correctly. As result I could run it locally on my pc, but not on my phone although I could run it with Safari on IOS. So switching to "older" syntax actually fixed my issue

Comment: I too have had issues with this, on Safari in particular. OP, let us know if it helped.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier it doesn't work even if I'm testing on a local server. Only on computers

Comment: @АндрейПовх could you please provide more of your code. Would be nice to have your html structure. And did you say that it works correctly on PC?